# Programatically add multiple horizontally stack views inside vertical stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

This is the layout I want to achieve

```
Label1 UIView Label2 <- horizontally stack view
Label1 UIView Label2
Label1 UIView Label2
Label1 UIView Label2
Label1 UIView Label2
```

Every horizontally stack view contains a label and view and another label. 
After that the horizontal stack view is added to a vertical one.

So all of that layout is a vertical stack view.

I want to achieve this inside a `UITableViewCell`. Here is my code:

```
let verticalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let hsv = UIStackView()
        hsv.axis = .vertical
        hsv.alignment = .fill
        hsv.distribution = .fill
        hsv.spacing = 10
        hsv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return hsv
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        for i in 1..<10 {
            let dayLbl: UILabel = {
                let l = UILabel()
                l.text = "Day " + String(i)
                l.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
                l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                return l;
            }()

            let progressBar: ProgressBar = {
               let pb = ProgressBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 12))
                pb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                return pb;
            }()

            let gradeLbl: UILabel = {
                let l = UILabel()
                l.text = String(i)
                l.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
                l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                return l;
            }()

            let horizontalStackView: UIStackView = {
               let hsv = UIStackView()
                hsv.axis = .horizontal
                hsv.alignment = .fill
                hsv.distribution = .fill
                hsv.spacing = 5
                hsv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                return hsv
            }()

            horizontalStackView.addSubview(dayLbl)
            horizontalStackView.addSubview(progressBar)
            horizontalStackView.addSubview(gradeLbl)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                horizontalStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12)
            ])

            verticalStackView.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
        }

        contentView.addSubview(verticalStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            verticalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
            verticalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            verticalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            verticalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
            ])
    }
```

This is what I get:

[image]

It was supposed to appear under the "Productivity Chart" title, but it appears on the cell content view x:0 y: 0 location. And there is only one line and everything looks crowded there.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

This is how one line should look:

```
Day 1 ----------------- 7   
(where ----- is the view).
```

edit:

After replacing `addSubView` with `addArrangedSubview`:

[image]

edit 2:

The right part truncated is fixed too. I changed:

```
verticalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20)
```

to

```
contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20)
```

Comment: @bseh: ohh I didn't know that. Yeah, now they appear under the title, but the right part is truncated also the last 3 rows. But it is a start

Comment: I updated the question with the new results. Now need to figure out why the right side is truncated and part of the bottom.

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer then :)

Comment: @yep, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding new subviews to a UIStackView, you should use [addArrangedSubview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616227-addarrangedsubview) method.

> The stack view ensures that the arrangedSubviews array is always a
>   subset of its subviews array. This method automatically adds the
>   provided view as a subview of the stack view, if it is not already. If
>   the view is already a subview, this operation does not alter the
>   subview ordering.

Comment: The link to a solution might not help as the ink might change in the future. It's better to add an answer here and reference to a link.

Comment: You are right, I added the description to my answer.